# Temperature coefficient of resistivity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, electrical-resistance

I came across a question recently:

> *A wire has a resistance of 2.1 ohm at 300 K, and 2.7 ohm at 373 K. What is the temperature coefficient of resistance of the metal?*

I tried by simply putting the formula R<sub>2</sub> = R<sub>1</sub> (1 + A(T<sub>2</sub> - T<sub>1</sub>)), and got the answer as 2/511.
But when I did -
R<sub>2</sub> / R<sub>1</sub> = R<sub>o</sub> (1 + A(T<sub>2</sub> - T<sub>o</sub>) / R<sub>o</sub> (1 + A(T<sub>1</sub> - T<sub>o</sub>)
taking T<sub>o</sub> as 273 K, I was getting 2/457.

This got me wondering, I can take any value of T<sub>o</sub> and get a different answer. Why is this so, since I am simply taking out the ratio here?

Answer (score 0):

Temperature coefficient of resistance, $\alpha$, is most easily defined in terms of Celsius temperature, $\theta$. Thus$$R_\theta=R_0 (1 +\alpha \theta)$$ in which $R_0$ is the resistance at temperature 0°C and $R_\theta$ is the resistance at Celsius temperature $\theta$.

Your second attempt is equivalent to using the above definition and is, I believe, correct.

Note that $R_0$ has to be the resistance at temperature 0°C; it can't be the resistance at some other temperature of your choice.